# Docker compose healthcheck use environment variables

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.1
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data:/data/db
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #volumes:
    #- ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysqldb
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    - 33060:33060
    expose:
    - 3306
    - 33060
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=somedb
    - MYSQL_USER=rstudio
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysql", "--user=$MYSQL_USER", "--password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD", "-e", "'SHOW DATABASES;'"]
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

How can I use environment variables `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`? In current setup I got following warning when running docker compose:

```
WARNING: The MYSQL_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Answer (score 45):

You need to use double-dollar sign (`$$`) in order to tell `docker-compose` not to parse these environment variables. Also change the way of defining a test as I tried to make it work but I couldn't without changing it. The following should work as expected:

```
test: mysql --user=$$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e 'SHOW DATABASES;'
```

`docker ps` result: `Up 35 seconds (healthy)`

Comment: I've tried test: ["CMD", "psql", "host=$$POSTGRES_HOST port=$$POSTGRES_PORT dbname=$$POSTGRES_DB user=$$POSTGRES_USER password=$$POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "-c", "SELECT 1"] and that didn't work even though I had $$, thanks for the syntax!

Comment: @KamilDziedzic maybe you need to pass each key and value within its own quotes. have you tried that already? like this `test: ["CMD", "psql", "host=$$POSTGRES_HOST", "port=$$POSTGRES_PORT", "dbname=$$POSTGRES_DB", "user=$$POSTGRES_USER", "password=$$POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "-c", "SELECT 1"] `

Comment: Test for Postgres 9.4+:
test: pg_isready -q -d $$POSTGRES_DB -U $$POSTGRES_USER

Comment: Consider using `mysqladmin` with `ping` instead of an SQL query.  This works for me: `test: mysqladmin --user=$$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD ping`.  Putting it within the `["CMD", ...]` or `["CMD-SHELL", ...]` constructs doesn't work.

Comment: How to do it in a docker run command? Unfortunately, it does not work like this.

Answer (score 4):

Your YAML looks OK, how are you invoking your env variables? Make sure you're referencing the correct object. Generally from your application you'd invoke your variables using something like

`process.env.MYSQL_USER`

You also don't need the dashes, my preference (for readibility) would be this syntax:

```
mysql:
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: somedb
    MYSQL_USER: rstudio
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

If you're trying to reference your env variable in the yaml config directly (i.e. in your tests command) you should use [ARGS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) instead as your env variables probably won't be compiled yet.

EDIT - if you want to reference an object within the yaml, you could use `self` e.g.:

```
test: ["CMD", "mysql", "--user=${self:services.mysql.environment.MYSQL_USER}", "--password=${self:services.mysql.environment.MYSQL_PASSWORD}", "-e", "'SHOW DATABASES;'"]
```

Comment: @ contool where should I execute `${self:services.mysql.environment.MYSQL_USER.sns}` from? Because in container exec return nothing.

Comment: Using `${self:services.mysql.environment.XXX}` just threw an error for me :(
Using `$$XXX` worked great!

Answer (score 2):

For me, Mostafa's (user: 2336650) answer does not work, but it set me in the right direction. The answer is correct in the aspect regarding `$` needs escaping in `docker-compose.yml`.

The missing piece is that the test command has more than one mode of execution; what we are interested in, in particular, is `CMD-SHELL`.

`CMD-SHELL` is different from `CMD` because it wrapped command execution inside `/bin/sh`, so shell syntax works. Since I used both environment variables and `&&` for multiple condition checking, I don't really sure what makes the health checking breaks in my case. (could be both)

For those who wandering for their answer, probably a different one from mine, the reference doc is worth a look.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete, tested, and working example that works for both mysql and mariadb:

```
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bad-password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=myDatabase
      - MYSQL_USER=myUser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=another-bad-password
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin -u $$MYSQL_USER -p$$MYSQL_PASSWORD ping -h localhost || exit 1"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
```